# Who knows about Loki's parentage?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, thor-marvel, asgardians

Loki is the second son of Odin, All-Father of the Asgardians. However,

> Loki is not an actual Asgardian, nor the natural born child of Odin and his wife Frigga. It is ultimately revealed that he is actually a Frost Giant of Jötunheim, the mortal enemies of Asgard.

Aside from the Asgardian royal family (Odin, Frigga, Thor and Loki) who else is aware of the unusual circumstances of his parentage?

**Note:** I am looking for both a canon comics answer, as well as an MCU answer (if one actually does exist... which I doubt... *yet*).

Comment: Edit to make the title clearer. I'm assuming you want a list of people who're "in the know" rather than asking whether rank and file Asgardians are aware (which they obviously aren't).

Comment: What defines being an Asgardian? Being born there, being of the race, or living and being raised there almost since birth, and it being the only home he's ever known (until the events of Thor)?

Comment: @phantom42 that sounds like an entirely different question. For the sake of this question let's say being of the race.

Comment: @phantom42 Sounds like the question is simply, 'who knows that it's Loki Laufreyson and not Loki Odinson?'

Comment: @Keen - Yes, ideally that would be the title but y'know, spoilers and all that...

Comment: I'm still wondering how Loki can be a Frost *Giant* ... nothing really gigantic about him ... ;-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As far as we know, the only people who know that Loki is not the natural-born son of Odin are Odin, Frigga, and Thor. Even Thor's close friends, who end up effectively rebelling against Loki in *Thor*, do so because they disagree with his actions. At no point do they seem to challenge the fact that he *is* the rightful heir to the throne, after Odin and Thor.

It's *possible* that Heimdall also knows; he certainly knows that Loki aided the Jotunn in getting into Asgard past him. However, Loki chose to kill the Jotun King to save Odin, which would likely go a long way to throwing suspicion off of him.

After that, we never really see Loki do anything Frost-Gianty anymore; he becomes fascinated with the Tesseract, and later with fighting off the Svartalf.

Unfortunately, we don't see very much of the noble court of Asgard, let along the rank-and-file army or civilians, so it's hard to know if *rumors* of his parentage have been floating around, but certainly, nothing definitive.

Comment: I'd say that if Heimdall knows or suspects, it's *more* likely that he knows because he could (probably) see Odin taking Loki as a baby.

Comment: More likely, Heimdall realized it when Loki froze him.http://vignette3.wikia.nocookie.net/marvelcinematicuniverse/images/f/fe/Loki.png/revision/latest?cb=20131111040724

Comment: Banner, Black Widow, Captain America, and Maria Hill at least know Loki is not a son of Odin, as after defending his brother, Widow says one tiny thing about having murdered a bunch of people before Thor retreats to "he's adopted".  They don't necessarily know who his real parentage is though.

Comment: Erik Selvig probably suspects, since he's familiar with the mythology.

Answer (score 7):

### **Everyone in Asgard knows.**

It's common knowledge by the time [Thor: Ragnarok](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thor:_Ragnarok) takes place.

> **Actor Odin:** *Loki, my boy...‘Twas many moons ago I found you on a frost-bitten battlefield. On that day, I did not yet see in you
>   Asgard’s savior. No. You were merely a little blue baby icicle... that
>   melted this old fool’s heart.*

[image]

Comment: The Asgardians have reason to doubt the entire story — even the parts that are actually true — after learning that Loki has been impersonating Odin.

Comment: @Gaultheria - That's true, but I suspect that such a revelation would stick in the mind.

Answer (score 1):

I can't speak to the Marvel Cinematic Universe.  I'll leave that to others.

In Marvel Comics, however, Loki's parentage was never any secret.  The following page is from *Journey into Mystery* #112 (1965), where the "Tales of Asgard" feature relates Loki's origins.  As the last panel shows us, Odin makes a loud and official proclamation of the adoption.  So be it known across the Realm Eternal!

[image]

(this page also offers an explanation to a few comments about Loki not being "giant-sized".)

Answer (score -1):

In the MCU it's probably Odin, Frigga and Heimdall (before he saw Loki in his Jotunn form or after he saw it). Later it's Thor and if we consider Ragnarok, all Asgardians (but I do not like it personally). In the comics all knew it from the start because Odin did not hide Loki's origin. Same thing with mythological Loki.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Please provide some references for this; the question is asking for canonical answers, not guesses.